# java hibernate fifo query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am creating an accounting app using java + hibernate. I have a table which represents inventory. Items bought and items sold.

DATE,BUY/SELL,PRICE, QTY

Say i have the following data;

```
1 buy 2.00 1
2 sell 2.25 1
3 buy 3.00 2
4 sell 2.90 1
```

how do I write a query that returns unmatched entries (buy without opposing sell or vic eversa)? and also how to get the matched ones? (assuming list will be much larger, and qty varying much more)

My idea was to take a sumproduct of sells and subtract from sumproduct of buys of the matched qty to represent inventory p&l and the unmatched entries as inventory that I still hold.

return:
 2.57 - 2.50 = 0.07 for matched orders (ie. P&L from Inventory)

and  (not in same function)

return: 3.00,1 (remaining inventory qty and price)

can I do this by a query or do I need to do several queries/manipulation?

trying to figure out if I can get the functionality in the QUERY line instead of inside the for loop...

```
public void findMatched() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    StringBuilder obsbmsg;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        **Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Inventory");**
        List orders = query.list(); 
        int i;
        i=1;
        obsbmsg= new StringBuilder();
        boolean check = orders.iterator().hasNext();
        if (check) {
            for (Iterator iterator = orders.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Orderbook obo = (Orderbook) iterator.next(); 

                // do stuff
            }
        } else {    
            System.out.println("No Entries in Table");

        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        session.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're working with hibernate, you'd have a entity mapping. Can you show us the relevant parts?

Comment: entities are mapped correctly.. i am wonder if/what would be the best sql query to accomplish

Comment: I'm not following: you have an `Inventory` entity you're querying and then you cast it to an `Orderbook`? Also, your order log needs to have a reference to the product being sold/bought. You could `GROUP BY` over the transaction type (buy/sell) and the product/product id and sum the corresponding entries.